# The meaning of the slope of the regression line

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

We know that the equation of the regression line of y to x is

$y = a + bx$

Where

$b=\frac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}}$

Now ,$b$

Is the slope of the line ,

My question is :-
Does the constant $b$ represents the intensity of the correlation between the tow variables like the the product moment correlation coefficient $r$?

I think they are completely different because $r\in[-1,1] $ but $b$ is not bounded .

If it is correct what does the constant $b$ say about the correlation between $x,y$?

Comment: b is known as the [regression coefficient](https://statisticsbyjim.com/glossary/regression-coefficient/) of y on x by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, they are not the same. You can look at correlation as a standardized slope between the $x$ and $y$, since correlation is covariance divided by the respective standard deviations:

\begin{align}
r_{xy} &=\frac{Cov(x,y)}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}
\end{align}

The constant $b$ doesn't tell us anything directly about the correlation. You can have a small value of $b$, with $y$ and $x$ highly correlated, and vice-versa. What $b$ does tell us, is how each increase in $x$ corresponds to a scaled increase in $y$, as $b$ is that scaling factor.

Comment: If the regression line equation is $y = 5-x $ Can we say that the correlation between $x $ ,$y$ is perfect inverse ? @Laur

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by perfect inverse, but you can say they are negatively correlated. I think we need to remember that the correlation is a function of **random** variables. If you have a **random** variable X and another one Y and you know Y = 5 - X you can definitely say they have a correlation of -1. However, usually you don't have such situations, so you can't say that in general.

Comment: Perfect inverse means that the moment correlation coefficient between x and y equals -1 ? Is this correct for that situation ? @Laur